# Laravel group models by date with 1 query

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-7.2

I was wondering if its possible to group appointments by dates with 1 query so my response will be something like this (in JSON):

```
{  
   "appointmentsByDay":[  
      "01-07-2018":[  
         {  
            "appointment":"test"
         },
         {  
            "appointment":"test"
         }
      ],
      "02-07-2018":[  
         {  
            "appointment":"test"
         },
         {  
            "appointment":"test"
         }
      ],
      ..................
      "31-07-2018":[  
         {  
            "appointment":"test"
         },
         {  
            "appointment":"test"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

I know this is possible looping through all the days within a Month but then I have to call a similar query up to 31 times for a single month.

Currently I'm getting all my appointments in between a month the way below but these are not grouped by each day and appointments falling between a bigger range will get ordered wrong:

```
$startOfMonth = Carbon::parse($date)->startOfMonth();
$endOfMonth = Carbon::parse($date)->endOfMonth();

$appointments = Appointment::
    where('user_id', '=', $userId)->
    where(function ($query) use($endOfMonth, $startOfMonth) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use($endOfMonth, $startOfMonth) {
            $query->where('from_date', '<', $startOfMonth->format('Ymd'))
                  ->where('to_date', '>', $endOfMonth->format('Ymd'));
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use($endOfMonth, $startOfMonth) {
            $query->where('from_date', '>=', $startOfMonth->format('Ymd'))
                  ->where('to_date', '<=', $endOfMonth->format('Ymd'));
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use($endOfMonth, $startOfMonth) {
            $query->where('from_date', '<', $startOfMonth->format('Ymd'))
                  ->where('to_date', '>=', $startOfMonth->format('Ymd'));
        })
         ->orWhere(function ($query) use($endOfMonth, $startOfMonth) {
             $query->where('from_date', '<=', $endOfMonth->format('Ymd'))
                  ->where('to_date', '>', $endOfMonth->format('Ymd'));
        });
    })
    ->with(user')
    ->get();
```

My model looks like this:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Reliese\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Appointment extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'appointments';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'from_date',
        'to_date',
        'title'
    ];
}
```

My appointments table looks like this: (I'm using MYSQL)

```
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| id (int)  | title (varchar)| from_date (varchar) | to_date (varchar) |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 1         | appointment1   | 20180725            | 20180725          |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 2         | appointment2   | 20180726            | 20180726          |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 3         | appointment3   | 20180723            | 20180812          |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 4         | appointment4   | 20180726            | 20180726          |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 5         | appointment5   | 20180612            | 20181123          |
+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Probably. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I have added all the information needed to find a possible solution.